# split dictionary in two 'by reference', not copying values

Tags: python, dictionary, split

How can one split a dictionary in two without creating new copies of the dictionary values?

```
original_dict = {'foo':'spam', 'bar':'eggs'}  
keys_for_dict1 = ['foo']  
dict1 = {}; dict2 = {}  
for key in original_dict:  
    if key in keys_for_dict1:  
        dict1[key] = original_dict[key]  
    else:  
        dict2[key] = original_dict[key]
```

This has created duplicates of the values of `original_dict`, so that modifying it does not modify `dict1` or `dict2`. (Iterating through `original_dict.items()` instead gives the same behaviour.) The values in my dictionary are very large objects which I want to avoid recreating. How can I capture the behaviour of `new_dict = original_dict`, which copies by reference, for this splitting-in-two scenario? Thanks.

Comment: You are **already** copying across references to the values. `dict1` and  `dict2` now reference the same string objects `original_dict` references. No copies have been made. If you used *lists* instead of `'spam'` and `'eggs'` that'd be immediately clear (just append to one of those lists and see the change show up in multiple locations).

Comment: "modifying it" - I guess you're re-assigning. show code.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I was re-assigning so couldn't see that they were all pointing to the right thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does what you want.  To make it clearer, let's use lists for the values.

```
original_dict = {'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6]}  
keys_for_dict1 = ['foo']  
dict1 = {}; dict2 = {}  
for key in original_dict:  
    if key in keys_for_dict1:  
        dict1[key] = original_dict[key]  
    else:  
        dict2[key] = original_dict[key] 

dict1['foo'][2]='a'
print dict1['foo']
print original_dict['foo']
```

The output is

> [1, 2, 'a']
>
> [1, 2, 'a']

So when I edited `dict1['foo']` it also changed `original_dict['foo']` because you **have not** created new copies.  It is the same object.

As a general rule in python, unless you put in the extra effort, when you do something like `a=b`, if `b` is some object, then you're actually making them point to the same thing, not be pointers to two initially identical objects.  You do not create a new copy unless you go to extra effort.